# flask structure at large app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have this slightly creepy file with views:

```
from app import app
from flask import request

inspection_handler = None
data_handler = None
repeat_handler = None

@app.route(START_URL + 'inspection/', methods=['GET'])
def inspection():
    return inspection_handler.update(request)


@app.route(START_URL + 'data/', methods=['GET'])
def data():
    return data_handler.update(request)


@app.route(START_URL + 'repeat/', methods=['GET'])
def repeat():
    return repeat_handler.update(request)
```

Another module has code like that:

```
from app.handlers.data.data_handler import DataHandler
import app.views.monitoring as monitoring

monitoring.data_handler = DataHandler()
```

I think I can really improve the first module but I don't know how to do it right. Can you help me ?

Comment: https://github.com/pallets/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to

Comment: What's so creepy about it? Besides, what are you trying to *improve*?

Comment: I have the common stat of `url` - `START_URL` and when I add a new route to it the module becomes some more bigger and unreadable. Can I use polymorphism better ?

Comment: Have a look at [Flask - Larger Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/) if you need a default package structure. If your app will start to grow it might be a good idea to stick to that.

Comment: @mike510a Why not to use `python` ? It's a quite simple language, isn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at flask [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/blueprints/), and as already recommended [Flask - Structuring Large Apps](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/)

```
from app import app  
from flask import Blueprint, request


handlers = {
    'inspection': None,
    'data': None,
    'repeat': None
}


handler_page = Blueprint(START_URL, __name__)
# Ideally register this blueprint where you registered your app
app.register_blueprint(handler_page)


@handler_page.route('/<string:handler_type>', methods=['GET'])
def handler_view(handler_type):
    try:
        curr_handler = handlers[handler_type]
    except KeyError:
        return "Not found.", 404
    return curr_handler.update(request)
```

Comment: Oh! That's great! But what can I do if I have a several `START_URL` ?

Comment: @faoxis You can do some clever refactoring using the `Request` methods, like `request.path` and `request.url`. Then based on the START_URL call the appropriate function from a dictionary. Or you can simply register *multiple* blueprints. Also, this is almost a non-issue. Don't think about structuring before running into severe problems. Don't fix what's not broken :)